# Big knot in my head, please help. (Nuclear fission and binding energy)

Tags: energy

Please look at these two links:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nucene/imgnuk/bcurv.gif
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Kernspaltung.svg/2000px-Kernspaltung.svg.png

When I now look at the binding energy of 235Uranium and its fission prodcuts 139Ba and 95Kr I find that their binding energy is higher which would mean that energy is NEEDED to make Ba and Kr. But I also know that energy is RELEASED in nuclear fission. So if someone could clarify I would be very thankful. Looking for a solution to this problem for quite some time now....

Answer (score 1):

First, the curve you are looking at is binding energy per nucleon, so it might not be the best thing to look at.  The other thing is that binding energy is negative.  Going to a more negative value means that energy is released.